# Print Specified extension files

Tags: java, string

I've to write a code that takes in file names as input in a String[] and returns all the files with extension name ".java".

This is my code:

```
    public String[] getJavaFiles(String[] fileNames){
    int l=fileNames.length;
    int count=0;
    int l2,i=0;
    String s;
    String dummy[]=new String[l];
    for (i=0; i<l; i++){
        s=fileNames[i];
        if ( s.endsWith(".java"))
            {
            dummy[i-count]=s;
            count++;
            }
        }
    String javaFileNames[]=new String[count];
    for (i=0; i<count; i++){
        javaFileNames[i]=dummy[i];
        }
    return (javaFileNames);
    }
}
```

I'm getting this output:

```
can.java
and.java
can.java
and.java.java
and.java.xys.pdf.java.doc.java
[Ljava.lang.String;@67d479cf
```

My Question is: What is this last line that I'm getting??:
**[Ljava.lang.String;@67d479cf**

Comment: You can simplify your `if` a lot: `if s.endsWith(".java") {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the end of a String with endsWith

```
if(s.endsWith(".java"))
```

You can use Arrays.toString to print an array

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(javaFileNames));
```

You have to do this because arrays are not very useful as plain objects e.g. toString, notify, wait, equals, hashCode don't do anything very useful for an array.

What might be better is to use a List

```
List<String> javaNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<l; i++)
    if (fileNames[i].endsWith(".java"))
        javaNames.add(fileNames[i]);
System.out.println(javaNames);
return javaNames.toArray(new String[javaNames.size()]);
```

Comment: Actually I'd to return the result. The function was 
public 
String[] getJavaFiles(String[] fileNames){`

Comment: Actually, the function was 
`public String[] getJavaFiles(String[] fileNames)`
So I had to return the String[] and not simply print it.

Comment: But I don't have to use lists. Can't it be done without the use of lists? I mean whats the mistake in my code?

Comment: You need to use Arrays.toString(array) to print the contents of an array (as stated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.endsWith`. It's simply:

```
String[] files = {"file1.java", "file2.java"};
for(String f: files)
     if(f.endsWith(".java"))
          System.out.println(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get  **[Ljava.lang.String;@67d479cf** as result of the default toString() method, defined in the Object class, called when you do a System.out.println of your array.

```
 public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

Your object is an array and by default java won't 'toStringify' its content.

Answer (score 0):

That is an hashcode string. You should not print array directly. Take out the values from the array `javaFileNames` and print.

```
for(int i = 0;  i < javaFileNames.length; i++)
    System.out.println(javaFileNames[i]);
```

Comment: The function being used is `public String[] getJavaFiles(String[] fileNames)`..so I have to return something and not just print it. That is why I was returning it.

Comment: after returning where you are printing, use the above code to print the values.